# Solid Angle Limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

So I was trying to compute the are of a sphere. There are many ways to do this like integrating small rings on the sphere etc. I was looking to do this using the notion of a solid angle.

What I know is that the surface element for a solid angle is

$dA = r^2 d\Omega$

I was wondering what to do further?

$\int dA = \int r^2 d\Omega$

What limits do I put in the above integral?

Comment: Go from $0$ to $4\pi$

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: That's because the definition of the solid angle (your first formula). If you compute the area of the sphere with other methods you get $4\pi r^2$. Now take $r^2$ outside your integral ang you get $\int d\Omega=4\pi$

Comment: Okay, so it's defined that way. But how is it working, like for example if I use the ring method, what I am doing them is stacking them on top of one other. What is happening when I use a solid angle?

Comment: It has the same meaning as if you use $dA$. If you have a ring with a given $dA$, it's solid angle is $dA/r^2$.